# How do I change the position of an image without it affecting the text to it's left?

Tags: html, css

CODE:

```
<div class="container_bottom_tip">
    <div class="container_bottom_desc">This is some text
        <img class="browser_button_img" src="images/something.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.container_bottom_tip {
    text-align: center;
}
.container_bottom_desc {
    color: #333;
}
```

Using the code above i want to move the image up a bit.  So when I do something like margin-top on the image it drags the text "This is some text" with it.

What can I do to move the image up or down without it affecting the positioning of the text "This is some text?"

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Is It in the div you are moving? Where is the JS? And are you moving by JS or CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
.browser_button_img
{
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

[Relative Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) will allow you to move the element relative to where it would have been without affecting other elements' reflow. Unlike absolute positioning, relative allows you to maintain the normal space taken up by an element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use position: relative

Then you can adjust the position of the image by changing the "top" property of the css.  This will move it around without affecting the parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/MCJhs/

```
.container_bottom_tip {
    text-align: center;
}
.container_bottom_desc {
    color: #333;
}
.browser_button_img{
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
}
```